# How to display Parent and child categories in lravel view?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 8 and i want to extract child categories according to parent id's. Below is output image.
[image]

Each item contains parent filed that represent its parent id. Now i want that in dropdown i display child categories below parent. I have following code,

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="categories">Product Category</label>
            <select class="select2 form-control select2-multiple" multiple="multiple"
                    data-placeholder="Select Product Category" name="categories[]">

                @forelse($categories as $keyParent => $category)
                    <optgroup label="{{$category->name}}">
                        <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
                    @foreach($categories as $keyChild => $sub)
                            @if($sub->parent === $category->id)
                                @unset($categories[$keyChild])
                                <option value="{{$sub->id}}">{{$sub->name}}</option>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </optgroup>
                @empty
                @endforelse
            </select>
        </div>
```

But i get child again. Below is out put,

[image]

Hoodies contain there child below but also repeat Man. How can i solve this. Thanks

Comment: can you post the relationship you declared in the Category.php model file?

Comment: Basically I am using woocommerce api so i have not created models.

Comment: I can see that all categories and subcategories are in one collection and the way to determine that a category is parent if its parent field is 0. If this is the case, I suggest you use recursive technique to loop through  collection.

Comment: can you help by modifying this code? Thanks

Comment: Sure. Let me try it.